# An error caused by "a WRITE memory access"

Tags: c, cs50

tbh I thought it wouldn't be hard to learn C seeing as I already know several other languages, but I'm having trouble with my code, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix these errors. I specialize in Python, so this is much different because of all the specifications for types, pointers, etc. Anyway, here's the code below, sorry, I would paste the error, but it won't allow me to copy paste. I was using some print functions and found the error to be coming from line 9, "*returnStr += *str";. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

char *multiplyString(const char *str, int num){
    char *returnStr = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        *returnStr += *str;
    }

    return returnStr;
}

int main(void){
    bool asking = true;
    int height;
    const char *symbol = "#";
    while (asking == true){
        height = get_int("How tall should the pyramid be? pick a number between 1 and 8: ");
        if (8 >= height && height >= 1){
            asking = false;
        }
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=height; i++){
        printf("%s  %s\n", strcat(multiplyString(" ", height-i), multiplyString(symbol, i)), multiplyString(symbol, i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `multiplyString()` to the following

```
char *multiplyString(const char *str, int num) {
    // + 1 for null-terminator
    char *returnStr = calloc(sizeof(*returnStr), strlen(str)*num + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        strcat(returnStr, str);
    }

    return returnStr;
}
```

You were attempting to modify a string literal, which is forbidden in C. Secondly, `+=` is not string concatenation in C; rather, it was trying to perform integer addition on the first character of `returnStr`.

To fix this, you dynamically allocate the proper amount of memory using `calloc()` (which also initializes the memory to 0, which is necessary for `strcat()`). Then, in each iteration, append the string using `strcat()` to the end of the new string.

Remember to free the strings returned by this function later in the program, as they are dynamically allocated.

Comment: `malloc` will not initialize the memory it allocates, its contents is *indeterminate*. The `strcat` function relies on it being null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- First of all, `returnStr` is pointing to a string literal, which is really an array of *read only* characters. In this case an array of only a single character, being the string terminator `'\0'`
- Secondly, `*returnStr += *str;` makes no sense. It's the same as `returnStr[0] = returnStr[0] + str[0]`. And since the destination (`returnStr[0]`) is a string literal, attempting to write to it leads to *undefined behavior*

If you want to create a new string containing `num` copies of `str`, then you need to create a new string containing at least `num * strlen(str) + 1` characters, the `+1` for the terminator. Then you need to use [`strcat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) to concatenate into that new string.

Also if you allocate memory dynamically (with e.g. `malloc`) then you need to make sure that the first element is initialized to the string terminator.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll make sure to keep this in mind.